# Changing class with Jquery in Ajax Suggestion Box

Tags: jquery, ajax, search, autosuggest

I am creating a suggestion search box and when I hit up or down to go through the suggestions it changes to the new hightlighted class for a brief moment and then reverts back to the default one.  The problem seems to be when I call my php with this line `searchReq.open("GET", '/search/ajax-suggest.php?search=' + str, true);` .  If I comment that out and hard code values into my search_suggest div then the functionality works fine. This php page is just echoing out values with a new line character after.

My input on the html page is

```
<form id="frmSearch" action="/search/index.php" method="get">

            <input type="text" id="zoom_query" name="zoom_query" alt="Search Criteria" onkeyup="searchSuggest(); " autocomplete="off"  />
            <input type="image" src="/images/search_button.gif" id="cmdSearch" name="cmdSearch" value="Search" alt="Run Search" /><br/>
            <div id="search_suggest">
            </div>
                        </form>
```

On My js page I have

```
function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
    alert("Your Browser is out of date");
}
}

//Our XmlHttpRequest object to get the auto suggest
var searchReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

//Called from keyup on the search textbox.
//Starts the AJAX request.
function searchSuggest() { 
if (searchReq.readyState == 4 || searchReq.readyState == 0) {
    var str = escape(document.getElementById('zoom_query').value);
    searchReq.open("GET", '/search/ajax-suggest.php?search=' + str, true);
    searchReq.onreadystatechange = handleSearchSuggest; 
    searchReq.send(null);   
}       
}

//Called when the AJAX response is returned.
function handleSearchSuggest() {
if (searchReq.readyState == 4) {
    var ss = document.getElementById('search_suggest')
    ss.innerHTML = '';
    var str = searchReq.responseText.split("\n");
    for(i=0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
    var suggest = '<div class="suggest_link">' + str[i] + '</div>';
        ss.innerHTML += suggest;
    }
}
}
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
var $hlight = $('div.suggest_link_over'), $div = $('div.suggest_link');
if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    $hlight.removeClass('suggest_link_over').next().addClass('suggest_link_over');
    if ($hlight.next().length == 0) {
        $div.eq(0).addClass('suggest_link_over')
    }
} else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    $hlight.removeClass('suggest_link_over').prev().addClass('suggest_link_over');
    if ($hlight.prev().length == 0) {
        $div.eq(-1).addClass('suggest_link_over')
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Can you load this into jsFiddle? It's a lot faster for us to help if we can see the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sure I put it  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CbZZg/2/) but this is still calling a php page with all my data in it so I'm not sure how to get that to work

Comment: can you give a small sample of the output html? you can also use firebug to see why the highlight reverts

Comment: Well my php page is resulting where it would output `echo $Name. "\n";` 5 times, then be changed into normal html output and inserted into my divs suggest_link.  If I manually put values in the suggest_link divs the code works fine, its just when I call my php page that it seems to be conflicting somewhere.  In firebug I just see the highlighted div quickly turn from suggest_link to suggest_link_over, then revert back quickly.  Im not sure how else I can use firebug to see why it reverts, is there some different method?